# Is there a way to create custom text on a alert in javascript html?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know if there's a way on customizing the button's text when a alert appears. An alert is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script> function functionAlert() {
   alert("the text will be "Okay" but is there a way to make it something else?")
}
<script>

<button class=".button .button1" onclick="functionAlert"()>button!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "customize?"

Comment: As in when you click a button that shows an alert and it has the button that says "Okay" to close it, is there a way to change that text from "Okay" to something else?